# c# .Net 8 How to decrypt pkcs7-envelopedData file encoded with aes128gcm?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, pkcs#7

I have an ecrypted file. It is in a PKCS7 enveloped file, encrypted with aes128gcm.
I spent more than two days trying to find the solution and I saw that many people have the same problem so I would like to share the solution.

OpenSSL information from the file:

```
contentType: pkcs7-envelopedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.3)
encryptedContentInfo:
contentType:
            pkcs7 - data( 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 )
      contentEncryptionAlgorithm:
algorithm:
            aes - 128 - gcm( 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.6 )
        parameter:
SEQUENCE:
            0:d = 0  hl = 2 l = 17 cons:
            SEQUENCE
    2:d = 1  hl = 2 l = 12 prim:
            OCTET STRING[ HEX DUMP ]:17B3CFB9CA81F40E16E2C253
   16:d = 1  hl = 2 l = 1 prim:
INTEGER:
     10
```

First I try to use the .Net functions: (use .Net 8 on win 11)

```
byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes( @"D:\EBT.enc" );

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2( @"D:\EBT_ENCR.PFX", "Abc123" );

// try with .Net, but .Net does not support aes128gcm :(
X509Certificate2Collection coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
coll.Add( certificate );
EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms();
System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo content = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo( encryptedData );
cms.Decode( encryptedData ); // The OID value is invalid.
cms.Decode(content.Content);// The OID value is invalid.
cms.Decrypt(coll);
```

it is failed, because .Net 8 does not support AES128GCM :(

I try it with Portable.BouncyCastle 1.9.0 (not a well documented tool...)

```
// Portable.BouncyCastle 1.9.0 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( File.ReadAllBytes( @"D:\EBT_ENCR.PFX" ) );
Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store st = new Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store( ms, "Abc123".ToCharArray() );

AsymmetricKeyEntry k = null;
foreach (Object a in st.Aliases)
{

    if (st.IsKeyEntry( (String) a ))
    {
        k = st.GetKey( (String) a );
    }
}

CmsEnvelopedData ced = new CmsEnvelopedData( encryptedData );
RecipientInformationStore rec = ced.GetRecipientInfos();
foreach (RecipientInformation r in rec.GetRecipients())
{
    String sn = r.RecipientID.SerialNumber.ToString( 16 ).ToUpperInvariant();
    if (sn == certificate.SerialNumber)
    {
        byte[] res = r.GetContent( k.Key );
        File.WriteAllBytes( @"D:\EBT_res.zip", res );
    }
}
```

But is failed at r.GetContent( k.Key ) here:

```
// ParameterUtilities.cs, canonical = "AES128"
ICipherParameters GetCipherParameters(
...
  int basicIVKeySize = FindBasicIVSize(canonical);
  if (basicIVKeySize != -1
      || canonical == "RIJNDAEL" || canonical == "SKIPJACK" || canonical == "TWOFISH")
  {
      iv = ((Asn1OctetString) asn1Params).GetOctets(); // Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1OctetString'.
  }
...
```

Then I try the BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll version 2.3.0.53016, but the Pkcs12Store works differently than in the portable version and I can't load the certificate with the private key using the Internet's suggested solution:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store st = new Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "Abc123" ) );
// Exception: Key not valid for use in specified state 
// StorePal.Windows.Export.cs:
//  if (!Interop.Crypt32.PFXExportCertStore( _certStore, ref dataBlob, password, Interop.Crypt32.PFXExportFlags.EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS | Interop.Crypt32.PFXExportFlags.REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY ))
//    throw Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error().ToCryptographicException();
// with X509ContentType.Pkcs12 I receive the same error

st.Load( stream, "Abc123".ToCharArray() );
```

ok, this means  private key is not exportable, but how to enable it in a PFX file? :)
let's try in this way:
`MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( certificate.RawData );`

I receive another exception:
illegal object in GetInstance: Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DLSequence
Here:

```
DerInteger.cs
  throw new ArgumentException("illegal object in GetInstance: " + Platform.GetTypeName(obj));
```

ok let's try another way:

```
byte[] certificateRawData = File.ReadAllBytes( @"D:\EBT_ENCR.pfx" );
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( certificateRawData );
st.Load( stream, "Abc123".ToCharArray() );
```

Yes! It works!

And then the rest of the codes (See above at Portable version) wors fine!

Comment: Hi yes, but decrypt with AesGcm requires nonce and tag informattion, I think (but i'm not sure) it is in the envelope file. Maybe we can read it fromo there, but we can not open the envelope file with .Net classes because the EnvelopedCms.Decode is failed. Do You know how to get this information from the enveloped file? I'm happy when i can decrypt without 3rd party tool. :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).